# Refile to a datetree to a date that does not appear in it

Tags: org-mode

I want to refile a headline to a datetree at 2016 -> 2016-10 October -> 2016-10-08 Saturday.

The datetree presently looks like:

```
* 2017
** 2017-11 November
*** 2017-11-30 Thursday
**** Something 1
**** Something 2
```

My refile target does not exist! But I am refiling in a datetree. So, I should be able to give an refile location of 'datetree' and it should be intelligent enough to create the datetree as needed. Or is it not?

Answer (score 1):

Refiling doesn't know how to handle datetrees. Out of the box, datetrees are only accessible via the capture process. However, the following code will refile a heading from within a buffer to a datetree heading in the same buffer. Note, though, that it won't work properly if you're trying to refile from one date to another - that will require more code to remove the existing date information from the heading before moving it to the new location.

```
(defun org-refile-to-datetree ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((date (calendar-read-date)))
    (save-excursion
      (org-datetree-find-date-create date))
    (save-excursion
      (org-mark-subtree)
      (org-datetree-file-entry-under
       (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end))
       date))
    (org-cut-subtree)))
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. Except that it does not 'refile' it copies (leaves the original in its place). And despite my `#+STARTUP: lorgefile`, it does not add the logbook entry. Any suggestions around that?

Comment: Oops = the revised code should move, not duplicate, the subtree. I'm not sure how to add the logfile.

Comment: Thanks. That works. But lets wait to see if someone comes up with a solution that will make appropriate entries in the logbook.

Answer (score 0):

I use this, which I adapted from [this Stack Exchange post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29413/13125) by [Tom Hunt](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/7095/tom-hunt). It prompts for the date you would like to refile, with today the default date.

```
(defun org-read-datetree-date (d)
  "Parse a time string D and return a date to pass to the datetree functions."
  (let ((dtmp (nthcdr 3 (parse-time-string d))))
    (list (cadr dtmp) (car dtmp) (caddr dtmp))))

(defun org-refile-to-archive-datetree ()
  "Refile an entry to a datetree under an archive."
  (interactive)
  (require 'org-datetree)
  (let ((dest (save-excursion
                (org-datetree-find-date-create
                 (org-read-datetree-date (org-read-date t nil)))
                (point))))
    (org-refile nil nil (list nil (buffer-file-name) nil dest))))
```